# What firebase check Email is valid or not used for new user registration?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am registering a user in firebase using wrong Email and Password authentication, It register the user successfully and when  ask for reset the password it is showing reset mail send successfully on firebase console. Is this is a bug or Firebase does not check wether the eamil is valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication does not automatically send verification emails. This is not a bug, since there are many scenarios where such an email may be unwanted or unnecessary.

If your app requires that the user's email address is verified before they can use you app, you will have to send it by calling [`sendEmailVerification`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email) from your app before allowing them access.